# Execute an Operation after a countdown in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a module where the user persists some data to the database then a sort of **countdown** starts, then after **it finishes** an operation gets fired up automatically without the user intervention. I want to know is there a way to do that?

> PS: I have thought about a JavaScript script but it depends on the
>   view the user is on and that's not my case here, it's a internal
>   server operation.

Comment: Depends on how long of a countdown. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling or https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#delayed-dispatching should do the trick.

Comment: @ceejayoz submit as answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how long of a countdown.

The [Laravel scheduler](http://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling) is (should be!) set up to run every minute, so you can write a custom command to run these delayed jobs based on a date/time stored in the database.

In some cases, the queue system may be appropriate - some queue drivers [permit delayed jobs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#delayed-dispatching). Note that there's a maximum delay for some drivers - Amazon's SQS won't let you delay more than 15 minutes, for example.